# Is it good idea to use RAID 1 mirroring to back up database content

Tags: mysql, innodb, mirroring, raid

I'm working on web hosting project. The planned system structure is going to be like this:

- one main hard-drive will contain the binary of mysql.
- A second hard-drive will contain the datadir
- the third hard-drive should contain a backup of this mentioned datadir.

I can only think of two options here either replication using 2 instances of MySQL servers or just using RAID 1 mirroring only the datadir.

I would go with mirroring but I'm kind of suspicious of using this method and my main frightening thought is what if I lost the main hard-drive that contain the binary of mysql does setting new version will cause my a problem .. any ideas suggestions will be great full thanks

I should mention that using INNODB is a constraint

Answer (score 2):

Relying on RAID 1 as a backup is not a great idea. If you had data corruption in the database, it would likely appear on both drives - certainly if it were caused by faulty SQL commands being executed. RAID 1 will only protect you from physical failure of one of the two drives, not corruption caused by a duff application or end-users.

In addition, backups that are stored on the same machine is also asking for trouble. You should always store backups off the source machine, and use something like `mysqldump` or the Percona `Xtrabackup` tool to perform these backups.

If you can mount an external volume onto the machine through NFS (or CIFS if Windows), then use Xtrabackup to backup the database content onto the additional volume, which is physically on a separate machine, then if you lost the machine, you could rebuild and restore from the backup.

Ensure you also backup your configuration, such as OS users, MySQL configuration files, etc. as without these, restoration may prove trickier.

Hope that all makes sense?

Dave

Comment: Mirroring protects against only one of many things that could go wrong -- disk failure.

Comment: Thanks Dave maybe I should mentioned that yes I actually planned to have forth drive where I will use it with mysqldump as will as for storing other mysql configuration it's like been 4 years and am trying to find the best solutions those what I call static data the problem using tool such as mysqldump is that you may lost some data for example if you are planing to take your backup automatically in every 12pm  and the disaster happened at like 11pm then you practically lost 1 hour of data so I have to come with the term live backup and offline backup for this project .

Comment: Agree with the potential for data loss, but using Xtrabackup allows you to perform incremental backups in addition to the full backups, which you could perform more frequently, say every 6 hours, and in addition you should be shipping the binlogs off to another server (can't remember the process off the top of my head, but it's fairly straight-forward). Just remember, the fourth drive inside the machine will not help if something goes wrong with the machine environment, such as fire or theft. Look at http://bit.ly/1XJPaux for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you could afford a second server then MySQL replication is a great way to keep an entire backup (slave) of the master database.

This has the added benefit of being an easy "failover" option: if you lose the server that is running the master database you can easily switch your DNS so that DB clients point to the slave server instead and everything keeps running like that until you can revive your master server.